# Do I need Mac OS X 10.6 to develop for the iPad?

Tags: ipad, ios

I downloaded Xcode and iOS SDK from the mac developer site. I tried to install it and it said **iOS SDK requires Mac OS X 10.6.4. You must upgrade to Mac OS X 10.6.4**

I am running bootcamp so I don't think upgrading is viable because I could lose my Windows installation right?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you maybe conflating Bootcamp with Hackintoshing, which definitely will NOT survive upgrading?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the newest SDK requires Snow Leopard.

No, upgrading will not make you lose your Bootcamp partition.

Comment: is there a version of xcode compatible with 10.6?? can i download it now??

Comment: Yes, just log in to Developer Center and look for a Snow Leopard download.